# got multiples number in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Make a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100,

which, if the numbers are multiples of three will print the word

"Max" (without the quotes two), and if the number is a multiple of five

will be scored "Good", and if the number is a multiple of three and five

both, then it will print "MaxGood".

here my script

```
<?php 
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
        echo "$x,";
    } 
    $check_number = 100; 
    for ($i = 1; $i < $check_number; $i += 3) 
    { 
        echo "<br>$i = Max"; 
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i < $check_number; $i += 5) 
    { 
        echo "<br>$i = Good"; 
    }   
    for ($i = 1; $i < $check_number; $i += 3 and $i += 5) 
    { 
        echo "<br>$i = MaxGood"; 
    } 
?>
```

the last function is wrong please help me

Comment: Use one loop, and modulus operator

Comment: can u write based on code? please i have any minutes to handle this problem :'(

Comment: Hope this is not an interview question !

Comment: `x%3 === 0 -> Max, x%5 === 0 -> Good, x%3 === 0 && x%5 === 0-> MaxGood`, sth like this??

Comment: can u give detail script andrew? help me please

Comment: This is a variant of the old FizzBuzz question, you'll want to use modulus `%` to see if the number is divisible and compare with `0` to check there is no remainder.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; i++) {
  echo $i;
  if($i % 3 == 0) echo "Max";
  if($i % 5 == 0) echo "Good";
  echo "<br/>";
}
```

php modulo is very practicable in this case.

http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php

greetings

Comment: nice to hear - please check my answer with your "solved" flag if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
    echo "$x, ";
    if($x % 3 == 0)echo 'Max';
    if($x % 5 == 0)echo 'Good';
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

for ($num = 1; $num <= 100; $num++) {
    if ($num % 3 == 0 && $num % 5 == 0)
        echo "MaxGood" . '</br>';
    elseif ($num % 3 == 0)
        echo "Max" . '</br>';
    elseif ($num % 5 == 0)
        echo 'Good' . '</br>';

    else
        echo  $num . '</br>';
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).